# The simplest way to install and use CGAL

Tags: c++, cgal

I want to compute a Delaunay triangulation in VSEx 2010 64, and would like to use CGAL in this purpose. I've already installed it. I included the "include" folder in my projects VC++ Directories. I don't want to use any software like CMake or Boost in order to get it working. Just simple steps. I receive the following error when compiling:

> fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'boost/config.hpp': No
>   such file or directory

This is some sample code of libraries included:

```
#include <CGAL/Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel.h>
#include <CGAL/Delaunay_triangulation_2.h>

typedef CGAL::Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel K;
typedef K::Point_2 Point_2;

using namespace std;
```

How am I supposed to get it going? Again, the simplest way possible, please.

Comment: "I don't want to use [...] Boost": well you don't have a choice, CGAL depends on it.

Answer (score 3):

The error you get:

```
fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'boost/config.hpp': No such file or directory
```

clearly indicates that **boost** header files (at least `boost/config.hpp`) are indirectly included by other headers you project requires, as such you need boost at least downloaded and added to include path.

Please refer to [CGAL installation guide](https://www.cgal.org/windows_installation.html)